# Using slim framework, put another website on a folder under public folder

Tags: slim

I am using Slim Framework, I need to put a wordpress under public folder.

slim-app/public/blog

The problema is when I do "www.myweb.com/blog" I obtain that "Page Not Found" is not found. By the momento I only have got this route in slim:

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");    
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', $args);
});
```

Do I need to put any special route to do this?

Comment: Is your .htaccess configured correctly? Your apache (or similar) as well?

Comment: Can you paste the content of `.htaccess` file here? I guess if you visit `www.myweb.com/blog/index.php` you'll see wordpress, if that is the case then the problem is in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Nima, the point is that I want to see wordpress with url "myweb.com/blog/" without index.php. When I use that url, slim enter in the process if it were his own route.

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez I know, I just suggested that for diagnosis purpose, to see if the problem comes from `.htaccess` configuration.

Comment: configure your server rewrite markup to ignore files and directories